# Haskell IDE Leskah cannot install

Tags: haskell, leksah

First did

```
sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

, then followed these instructions...

https://github.com/leksah/leksah#building-on-linux

Set PATH in ~/.profile to "PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH""

```
sudo apt-get install libgtksourceview-3.0-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev
cabal update
cabal install Cabal cabal-install
cabal install regex-tdfa-text --ghc-options=-XFlexibleContexts
cabal install alex happy
cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
cabal install leksah
leksah
```

Got this horrendous error message on "cabal install leksah"...

```
Installing executable(s) in /home/johnreedlol/.cabal/bin
Installed gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.0.5
johnreedlol@johnreedcomputer:~/leksahFolder$ cabal install leksah
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: leksah-0.15.1.4
trying: hlint-1.9.28
rejecting: haskell-src-exts-1.17.1, 1.17.0 (conflict: leksah =>
haskell-src-exts>=1.13.5 && <1.17)
rejecting: haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1, 1.16.0, 1.15.0.1, 1.15.0, 1.14.0.1,
1.14.0, 1.13.5 (conflict: hlint => haskell-src-exts>=1.17 && <1.18)
rejecting: haskell-src-exts-1.13.4, 1.13.3, 1.13.2, 1.13.1, 1.13.0, 1.12.0,
1.11.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.1, 1.10.0, 1.9.6, 1.9.5, 1.9.4, 1.9.3, 1.9.0, 1.8.2,
1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.7.2, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.5.3, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5.0,
1.4.0, 1.3.5, 1.3.4, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.0, 1.1.4, 1.1.3.1, 1.1.3,
1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.5.7, 0.5.6, 0.5.5, 0.5.4, 0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.4.8,
0.4.6, 0.4.5, 0.4.4.1, 0.4.4, 0.4.3.1, 0.4.3, 0.4.2, 0.4.1, 0.3.12, 0.3.11,
0.3.10, 0.3.9, 0.3.7, 0.3.5, 0.3.4, 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.2.1 (conflict: leksah =>
haskell-src-exts>=1.13.5 && <1.17)
johnreedlol@johnreedcomputer:~/leksahFolder$
```

Ultimately went with "sudo apt-get install leksah"

Comment: IMO the way you went is definitely recommended ... as long as you are happy with the result you should not put that much stuff into unprotected (aka non-sandboxes/non-stack) land

Comment: All the dependencies are messy and out of control, leksah is a lazy, buggy mess, this is why going open source is sometimes bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here we are in the first ring of dependency hell: hlint wants haskell-src-exts in the range [1.17, 1.18) and leksah wants it in the range [1.13.5, 1.17). If we wanted to build the project rather than use apt-get, we can

- wait for the leksah package maintainer to update the upper bound,
- do it ourselves,
- or clone leksah/leksah and use `stack build`.

Leksah has a [stack.yaml](https://github.com/leksah/leksah/blob/master/stack.yaml) set up, which means it should Just Work™ with [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack). Note that bullet one seems unlikely. The leksah project sadly is in a state of stasis.